# Changing Terraform provider.go file

Tags: terraform

I'm modifying Terraform provider.go file locally for development testing purposes. I need to add efs endpoint, something that looks like this

```
"efs": {
                    Type:        schema.TypeString,
                    Optional:    true,
                    Default:     "",
                    Description: descriptions["efs_endpoint"],
                },
```

I'm trying to put it under [endpointsSchema function](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/vendor/github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/aws/provider.go#L796)

My question:

What is required to successfully build Terraform locally with my changes?

Do I need to manually build the plugin and place it under home/user/.terraform.d/plugins ([link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/plugins/basics.html#installing-a-plugin))? Or `make dev` for Terraform would be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by modifying the endpoints as in [this PR](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/2795/files).
Terraform searches for plugins in $GOPATH/bin. My advice is to run terraform from $GOPATH/bin and having the plugin in the same directory. For some reason, Terraform wasn't able to pickup the plugin properly otherwise.